# Multiple Bibliographies and Libraries

Tags: bibliographies

I use BibTex and I want to insert a second bibliography only for webpages.
I therefore created another bib.file "Webseiten". My main library is "Literatur".
Now i tried to include it as follows:

```
    \bibliographystyle{jf} %Reference style.
    \bibliography{Literatur}

    \newpage

    \bibliographystyle{jf}
    \bibliography{Webseiten}
```

But the only thing that changes is that i get my main bibliography a second time.

How can I include this second bibliography the right way?

It is probably trivial but I'm new to Latex.

It would be fantastic if anyone could help me! Cheers.

Comment: The easiest  way to do this is with `biblatex`. See § 3.6.7 *Bibliography Categories*, p. 81 of the documentation